# Javafx web browser node?

Tags: firefox, browser, javafx, webview, applet

I am writing a program in JavaFX (regular app, not applet) which uses WebView(a node to browse internet).
WebView renders websites but doesn`t support rendering applet inside the WebView(website).

I`ve been looking for a node that allows me to render internet with applet support but I failed. So do you know the solution?

If no one can help me with finding such Node, maybe you`ll help me another way:
I need to render firefox inside my program - another words I want to allow user to browse internet inside my program but with applet support.

My firefox supports rendering applet so maybe I can use it, but how?

Thank you for your replay

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of topics on this as it seems to be a fairly highly request feature of javafx but to put it simply in someone elses words

> WebView in JavaFX 2.2 does not support plugin based content such as
>   Flash content.

However you can use [HostService](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29) and implement JavaScript work-arounds for some content such as [youtube support](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

But note getHostService will open the document in your default browser:

```
getHostServices().showDocument("http://www.youtube.com/v/glKR892dYrQ?version=3&feature=player_detailpage");
```

Applet support is tricky in Javafx and workarounds kind of exist, but are usually unstable as not much of the webkit api is exposed through Javafx. However you may wish to check out this native browser for swing as you could use Javafx-Swing support to include it in your application.

[The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Webview has no support for java applet.  The netscape.javascript.JSObject in the jfxrt deliberately dumbs down the getWindow(Applet) method, to make applet work in the webView, you have to provide the code to parse the html for the  tag and then instantiate the applet class (maybe using AppletStub), and then set the parameter (if any) and init() it.  You may have to override the JSObject as well.  The webfx project has some sample code, see https://github.com/brunoborges/webfx/tree/master/webfx-appletsupport-sample